# "Difficult" join between string type arrays

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

My apologies for the strange title. I'm not entirely sure that this is doable in sql-like (redshift) but we can try.
I have two tables. One (named **asm**) with something like (all types are text):

```
hashid                            kuids
00009fff755fb6cafbfe1d3262d0a6d4  [LDydc6kP, LBzCi_CB, LBrFy7Ot]
000bcb9ce17770ebb981e761ca71d395  [K2zw2pRu, LBbGkhWm]
```

and another named **la** like:

```
kuid        lakuids
LDydc6kP    [KEqeQBJ8, KOvcq6TZ, K2zw2pRu, LQwVKtec, J6lfIKfY]
Lb7PtjUG    [JBsQJf1O, LcmasXTm, JkN5IhP4, LBbGkhWm]
```

1) if kuid in **la** is at least in one element of kuid in **asm** -> put hashid from **asm** in **la** into a new column (hashid) in **la** (same row) otherwise put 'None'

2) Create new columns lahashids where the value is the list of kuids vs. hashid mapping in table **asm**, and unknown column is the list of lakuids not present in  kuids table **asm*

I know, it looks strange. I'm open to change type and table structure....

The expected answer should be for **la** table

```
kuid        lakuids                                              hashid                             lahashids                                  unknown      
LDydc6kP    [KEqeQBJ8, KOvcq6TZ, K2zw2pRu, LQwVKtec, J6lfIKfY]   00009fff755fb6cafbfe1d3262d0a6d4   [000bcb9ce17770ebb981e761ca71d395]         [KEqeQBJ8, KOvcq6TZ, LQwVKtec, J6lfIKfY]                         
Lb7PtjUG    [JBsQJf1O, LcmasXTm, JkN5IhP4, LBbGkhWm]             None                                None                                      [JBsQJf1O, LcmasXTm, JkN5IhP4, LBbGkhWm]
```

Comment: If this is anything like tsql/mysql then you should be using a one to many relationship between hashid => kuid and another one to many relationship between kuid => lakuid. This will simplify your joining.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the expected output based on that your samples.

Comment: Have a look at the example I edit,

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Python UDF for array matching that returns boolean like this (had to deal with the same issue in the past so I share):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_inlist(element varchar, list varchar)
RETURNS boolean
STABLE AS $$ 
if list==None:
    return False
list = list.strip('[').strip(']').split(',')
if (element in list):
    return True
else:
    return False
$$ LANGUAGE plpythonu;
```

so you can use this function as join condition just like this:

`ON f_inlist(element_column, list_column)`

of course it's slow, so better to avoid such structure and unwrap lists into multiple rows, but if it can't be avoided this is a way to go

Comment: Thank you Alex. I'll try this. The table at the moment is 4.5M and i'd like to avoid the unwrap.